# Full page cache not working, appears to be caching per session instead of per user group

Tags: magento-1, cache, full-page-cache

Full page caching appears to be working on a per session basis.

- If I go to a page, the first page load takes a few seconds, the second page load much less
- If my co-worker visits that same page, it takes a few seconds and the second page load much less.

We have exhausted all the FPC documentation, tutorials, and posts we can find. We are completely out of ideas, We have hole punched the one per session object on our pages (cart contents) and FPC still appears to only work on a per session basis instead of on a user group basis like we would expeect.

Any idea why this would be occurring?

Comment: What are you using for the full page cache and how do you have your cache storage configured?

Comment: davidalger: I'm one of the coworkers. We're using enterprise edition full page cache with memcached as the storage engine.

Comment: Have you tried this test on a clean EE install with sample data? To eliminate the possibility that it's something custom you've introduced vs a bug/configuration with magento core?

Comment: using the enterprise theme I have confirmed that it is on a per session basis, I modified the method that saves the cache to echo "This request will be cached".... I load a page in my browser, it echo's that response the first time, not the second, I open an incognito browser, and it echo's that response the first time and not the second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing isn't default behaviour.

Typically as FPC is primed, when not logged in - or having done anything to make the session specific to you, the page load timeline tends to be:

```
--1.2s--------0.8s------------------0.6s-----------------------0.1s---------------
  Uncached    Mage default cache    Partially cached in FPC    Fully cached in FPC
```

What *should* happen is that a single page load primes the Magento cache and to a lesser degree, the Magento FPC cache. The subsequent load for the same content fully primes the FPC cache resulting in a 3rd page load for the same content to take around 0.1s.

But when you do something to make your session unique, eg, add-to-cart - then FPC exhibits slightly different behaviour and the render times do increase slightly.

```
--1.4s--------0.8s------------------0.6s---------------
  Uncached    Mage default cache    Fully cached in FPC
```

It sounds like you've broken the FPC logic by make your amendments (hole-punches) by essentially causing FPC to behave like in my second example.

Ie. It doesn't serve any content from a global cache, but rather only content specific to your session

My suggestion would be to either install a clean EE store - and watch the behaviour there - or move the local/community directories and custom theme package directories (to force enterprise/default to load).